# How to solve this recurrence involving binomial coefficients?

Tags: recurrence-relation, generating-functions

How to solve the following recurrence involving binomial coefficients, where $c$ is a constant non-negative integer, and $n$ and $k$ are non-negative integers ($n \ge k \ge 0$)?

$$
A(n,k) = A(n-1,k) + A(n-1,k-1) + c, \\
A(n,0) = 1, A(n,n) = 1
$$

---

***My Attempt:***
Without the constant $c$ (or $c=0$), $A(n,k)$ is just $\binom{n}{k}$.

I have tried the generating function 
$$
g(x,k) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} A(n,k) x^n.
$$
I need to evaluate 
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} A(n+1,k) x^n &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\big(A(n,k)+A(n,k-1) + c\big)x^{n} \\
&= g(x,k) + g(x,k-1) + \frac{c}{1-x}
\end{align}
$$

On the other hand,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} A(n+1,k) x^n = \frac{1}{x} \big(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} A(n,k) x^n\big) = \frac{1}{x}\big(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} A(n,k) x^n - A(0,k)\big).
\end{align}
$$
How to handle with $A(0,k)$? How to establish an equation for $g(x,k)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us guess that $A(n,k) = \alpha \binom{n}{k} + \beta$. The recurrence reads
$$
\alpha \binom{n}{k} + \beta = \alpha \binom{n-1}{k} + \beta + \alpha \binom{n-1}{k-1} + \beta + c,
$$
from which we deduce $\beta = -c$. The base cases are
$$
\alpha \binom{n}{n} - c = \alpha \binom{n}{0} - c = 1,
$$
From which we deduce $\alpha = c+1$. All in all, the solution is
$$
A(n,k) = (c+1) \binom{n}{k} - c.
$$

Comment: Are there any clues for you to guess that $A(n,k) = \alpha \binom{n}{k} + \beta$?

Comment: Experience. Perhaps more interesting is to solve the recurrence when $A(n,0) \neq A(n,n)$.

Comment: I just found that I have made a mistake: The initial conditions should be $A(n,0) = A(n,n)  = 0$ instead of  $A(n,0) = A(n,n) = 1$. $A(n)$ aims to count the number of additions in computing $\binom{n}{k}$ following the identity $\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n-1}{k-1} + \binom{n-1}{k}$. I failed to apply your method with such initial conditions. Therefore, I have removed the code and the backgroud, leaving only the recurrence to solve. However, can you solve this recurrence with the new initial conditions? (Maybe I should open a new post.)

Comment: Try again. My method works just as well in this case.

Comment: I have obtained that $A(n,k) = c\binom{n}{k} - c$. Thanks.